# Multiple filters on list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data that currently has a filter for category.

```
this.data = response.data.items.filter(item => item.category_id === categ_id)
```

I want to add another filter which would only display items with a specific count.

EG:

```
this.data => items with category id of "categ_id" and quantity above 0
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: `response.data.items.filter(item => item.category_id === categ_id && item.quantity > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical and operator (`&&`) to `and` conditions

```
this.data = response.data.items.filter(item => item.category_id === categ_id && item.quantity > 0)
```